# Set width Imageview programmatically

Tags: android, height, width, set, imageview

I already try many ways but it seems doesn't work with me.

my code : 

`TableLayout tTopic=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.__topic);`

```
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams lpt2=null;
    lpt2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lpt2.setMargins(4, 2, 4, 2);

    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(20,30));

    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.kotak);


    tr.addView(view);
    tTopic.addView(tr,lpt2);
```

Why it doesn't appear at all? but when I omitted setLayoutParams it appear as default size. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(20,30));
```

Answer (score 1):

To set ImageView width programmatically do this:

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
```